# Spring Boot bootstrap icons not showing on HTTPS reload

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, font-face

Looked everywhere online for a solution to this but nothing seems to work.

On localhost the .EOT file downloads with a 200 result and mime type of application/octet-stream.

On HTTP the same happens.

When using HTTPS, we still get a 200 result but also seem to take down the .WOFF and .TTF file, however they are only 283 Bytes in size when expecting around 20KB.

We are unsure if its caching or the mime types are not right on HTTPS. We have an import.jsp file that is used in every page as so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=3600 , must-revalidate" />
```

When using the bootstrap CDN, it works perfectly and shows a mime-type of vnd.ms--fontobject. Unsure how this is even making a difference?

Obviously using the CDN is a fix but not a solution to the problem. We do not wish to do this in case a server connection to the CDN fails.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out after much trial and error. 
Removed any code both xml and java based and created this one class that has brought caching to the spring boot system.

I point the resources folder to cache all javascript and css for an hour at a time.

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
        .setCachePeriod(3600);
    }
}
```

This now shows 304s and the bootstrap icons remain on refresh.